# Copy/paste values using google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Here is the sheet with an example of the data that I'm using

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_k3xclEgdREfMMks7H2-uk0tzxXqCaoeVW_G8ase-3o/edit?usp=sharing

I only put the formulas on the rows without color, and the information about the schedule comes from other tab.

the colors in green are the ones with dates, where I store inside the numbers, and the blue ones also contain formulas and I wanna skip those columns when pasting the values because is correlated to another worksheet, so I can't paste the values

I've tryied two ways

this first one I receive an erro message: **Exception: The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues.**

```
//destination = sheet.getRange(1,colA[j],table.length,1)
//destination.setValues(table); // where we paste the values by column
```

For this one, it paste on other tab on the first columns

```
//sheet.getRange(1,colA[j],table.length,1).copyTo(sheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
```

Here is the script that Im using

```
function PasteValues() {
  var ss =  SpreadsheetApp.openById("...");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Testsheet");
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var dates = rows[2];
  //Logger.log(dates)
  var yesterday = new Date(Date.now() - 864e5);
  var numbers = [];
  
  
  for(var i = 2; i < dates.length; i++) {
    let columns = i
    if (dates[i]!==""  &&  dates[i] !== null){
      numbers.push(columns);
    }
    
    if (dates[i]==="") {
    continue;
    }
    if (dates[i].getDate() == yesterday.getDate() && dates[i].getMonth() == yesterday.getMonth() ){
      break;
    }
  }
  colA=numbers.slice(-5)


  var table = [];
  Logger.log(rows.length)
  Logger.log(colA)
  for(var j=0;j<colA.length;j++)
  { 
    table =[];
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length;i++ )
    { 
     table[i] = rows[i][colA[j]];
    }
    Logger.log("the number of the column is: "+colA[j]);
    Logger.log(table);
    // where I paste the data

  }
  
}
```

This is the example on how my data is to copy/paste it based on the column number

[image]

Comment: I updated my answer to explain you your error source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### When you retrieve values from the spreadsheet, `getValues()` already returns them to you in a 2-D array - there is no need to manually transfer them into another array

You can either do:

```js
var table = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
destination = sheet.getRange(1,statColumn,table.length,table[0].length);
destination.setValues(table);
```

Or:

```js
sheet.getDataRange().copyTo(sheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
```

### UPDATE

> Exception: The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature
> for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues.

means that you are trying to assign a row (1-D array) to a range (2-D array).

Also, `table.length` will retrieve you the number of columns and not rows if `table` is a row.

This can be easily solved by defining:
`table = [table];`

**Sample snippet:**

```js
  for(var j=0;j<colA.length;j++)
  { 
    table =[];
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length;i++ )
    { 
      table[i] = rows[i][colA[j]];
    }
    Logger.log("the number of the column is: "+colA[j]);
    table = [table];
    Logger.log(table);
    // where I paste the data
    destination = sheet.getRange(1,colA[j],table.length,1)
    destination.setValues([table]); // where we paste the values by column 
  }
```

### UPDATE

If what you want is to copy paste selected data column by column, you need to create a 2D array `table` and populate it as following:

```js
  for(var i = 2; i < dates.length; i++) {
    let columns = i
    if (dates[i]!==""  &&  dates[i] !== null){
      numbers.push(columns);
    }
    
    if (dates[i]==="") {
      continue;
    }
    if (dates[i] instanceof Date && dates[i].getDate() == yesterday.getDate() && dates[i].getMonth() == yesterday.getMonth() ){
      break;
    }
  }
  colA=numbers.slice(-5)
  
  
  var table = [];
  Logger.log(rows.length)
  Logger.log(colA)
  for(var j=0;j<colA.length;j++)
  { 
    
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length;i++ )
    { 
      table[i] =[];
      table[i][0] = rows[i][colA[j]];
    }
    Logger.log("the number of the column is: "+colA[j]);
    Logger.log(table);
    // where I paste the data
    destination = sheet.getRange(1,colA[j],table.length,1)
    destination.setValues(table); // where we paste the values by column 
  }
```

It is important to make sure that the array is 2-dimensional and that its dimensions (rows and columns) correspond to the dimensions of the range into which you want to set the data.

Comment: Hey @ziganotschka, thank you for this comment, about the variables, where I stored the table is the entire column of information that I wanna paste it. the variable rows is where is store the size of the sheet

Comment: But also I used the modifications and it only paste the first row of the data and paste the values in sequence not for the columns that are stored =/

Comment: Maybe if you provide a copy of a sample spreadsheet with data and explain your issue more in detail it will become clearer?

Comment: For sure, just need sometime to take and share here. Thanks for your time!

Comment: I added on the post the link for the google sheet, its an example of the data that I'm using on my work

Comment: I am not quite sure what your desired output is. Do you want to transpose the data and set it in columns starting with AJ? Something like `for(var j=0;j<colA.length;j++)
  { 
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length;i++ )
    { 
      table[i] =[];
      table[i][0] = rows[i][colA[j]];
    }
    destination = sheet.getRange(1,colA[j],table.length,1);
    destination.setValues(table);      
  }`? Mind that you should check: `if (dates[i] instanceof Date && dates[i].getDate() == yesterday.getDate() && dates[i].getMonth() == yesterday.getMonth())`

Comment: My output is to paste the values on the columns where display the dates (green), and avoid to paste on the columns with "EOW" (blue) cause the formula on those columns are linked with other place and I cant paste it. What I wanna do, is take the columns with the 5 previous days (comparing to todays date) and paste the values. I'd like to paste it using the column number, that is stored on the "colA"

Comment: on the picture that I add it displays the columns where I'd like to copy/paste the values, then avoiding to paste on the blue columms

Comment: I am not sure if I fully understood your issue (do you want to overwrite the data contianing formulas with fix values?). In any case I updated my answer showing how you can copy-paste data column by column - I hope this is helpful!

Comment: Yes, thats my point, but only overwrite on the green columns, cause the blue ones I cant overwrite, that is why I store the column numbers where have the dates on the row 3

Comment: and thanks a lot for your effort and time to help me!!!

Comment: shouldn't it be ```getDataRange()``` instead of ```getDataRange``` in your second block of code?

Comment: Yes @DanCue, sorry for the typo!